# Adding two nullable integers not working

Tags: c#, nullable

I am having a very strange problem. Problem looks funny and simple but its making me mad.

I have a nullable integer in a class which are declared as

```
public int? count { get; set; }
```

I have an array of objects(additionalCell) of this class and another object of the same class called currentPixelTotalCell. I want to add values of the count variable of all the objects in the array and store it in the count variable of currentPixelTotalCell.

My code is as below. But when debugging, i see that the left hand part has value as null only after the loop is exited although count variables in all the object have non-null value.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{    
    currentPixelTotalCell.count += additionalCell[i].count;
}
```

Any idea why is this happening ? Is there a different way to add them ? I am clueless.

Edit:

Forgot to mentioned this. When I have breakpoint and check in first iteration itself, it doesnt add up.
Eg. If additionalCell[0].count was 10. Then value of currentPixelTotalCell.count used to be null only even after the inner line was executed in first iteration.

Comment: you need to extract the value of the nullable. Instead of `.count` it should be `.count.Value`.

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz: which will throw an exception if there is no value. Not sure if this is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that you need to initialize the `currentPixelTotalCell.count` variable to 0 first?

```
currentPixelTotalCell.count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{    
    currentPixelTotalCell.count += additionalCell[i].count;
}
```

or you may have to check for null values in AdditionalCell objects?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{    
    currentPixelTotalCell.count += (additionalCell[i].count ?? 0)
}
```

Comment: Looks like I need to do both infact. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `null` as the result then

- Either `currentPixelTotalCell.count` is `null`
- Some of additionalCell[i].count is `null`

Ensure that both `null` are under control

```
   // currentPixelTotalCell.count is not null
   currentPixelTotalCell.count = 0;

   for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {    
       // if additionalCell[i].count is null treat it as 0
       currentPixelTotalCell.count += additionalCell[i].count ?? 0;
   }
```

you can try *Linq* as an alternative:

```
   currentPixelTotalCell.count = additionalCell
     .Take(5) // if you want take just first 5 items
     .Sum(item => item ?? 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your inner loop to:

```
currentPixelTotalCell.count += (additionalCell[i].count ?? 0);
```

to avoid setting your total to null in case one of the right handed values is null.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the result is `null` because one of the values is `null`.

What about:

```
 currentPixelTotalCell.count += additionalCell.Select(x => x.count)
                                              .Where(x => x.HasValue)
                                              .Sum();
```

Or

```
 currentPixelTotalCell.count += additionalCell.Sum(x => x.count ?? 0);
```

Don't forget to initialize `currentPixelTotalCell.count` somewhere or replace `+=` by a simple assignment `=`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise currentPixelTotalCell.count to 0 before accesing it.

Remember that "*a += b*" is just syntactic sugar for "*a = a + b*".

Because a is null, you are effectively doing "*a = null + b*" and null plus something equals null.

Also because of the same constraint, you need to ensure the value on the right hand side is also not null. The easier way to do this in your case is to simply use the *GetValueOrDefault* method.

All this being said, your final solution should be something like:

```
currentPixelTotalCell.count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{    
    currentPixelTotalCell.count += additionalCell[i].count.GetValueOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called [`.GetValueOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0(v=vs.110).aspx) which will give you the default value of the `Nullable<T>`. You can make use of it to assign `0` if the value is `null`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{    
    currentPixelTotalCell.CmvF =currentPixelTotalCell.CmvF.GetValueOrDefault() +  additionalCell[i].CmvF.GetValueOrDefault();
}
```